# Difference between jQuery.autocomplete and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have a search field in my site and I wanted it to autocomplete when my users typed in their searches. At first, I looked into ajax but found it to be kind of tricky for a newby like myself. Then I found the jQuery.Autocomplete option and I was able to implement that with no problem.

My question is, is there any difference between Ajax and the jQuery.autocomplete function or is the autocomplete function just a shorthand version of Ajax. I went with the autocomplete function because it seemed easier to grasp, but if there are advantages to using Ajax to implement autosuggest then I'll try to learn it again.

note: I'm pulling the data from a mysql server. They are searching through a mysql table for other users.

Comment: What is the source for your autocomplete data? A database on the server side? An array on the clientside? Anything else?

Comment: my source is a mysql server. They are searching for users on a site.

Comment: Well, actually I have never used the autocomplete function mentioned but it seems to be pretty straight forward I think. Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656523/jquery-autocomplete-with-callback-ajax-json ?

Comment: Autocomplete can utilize AJAX when you need to dynamically query your DB. Autocomplete is a plugin of sorts whereas AJAX is a method used to make silent HTTP/s calls