# Auto complete for all fields in web form

Tags: jquery, mysql, forms, autocomplete

Iv'e been struggling with this issue for days now and although there are tutorials online, I can't seem to incorporate it into my own web form.

I'm trying to get my web form autocomplete ready, meaning lets say I start typing a name in the "name" text field, it must give me the autocomplete options and after I selected the correct option, the other fields in the web form must also automatically populate.

The closest tutorial iv'e seen so far is:http://af-design.com/blog/2010/05/12/using-jquery-uis-autocomplete-to-populate-a-form/
But I couldn't get it to work.

I do have a control on my page already which allows me to move between records but we have 1000+ records and the users need to update it regularly.

How can I use jquery autocomplete to link to MySQL database to perform this task?

ps, I tried pasting my code here but it shows up "unformatted" (looks like plain text)

Comment: Use a serverside language e.g. php, perform the search and return the result ... thats all

Comment: When posting your code, just indent four (4) spaces and then paste. It should show up as code. Without it there's no way to help you.

Comment: Create auto complete using JQuery UI autocomplete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656523/jquery-autocomplete-with-callback-ajax-json. After you receive reply with id, value in the sucess callback you can again have a ajax request that will populate the data for other web form controls...

Comment: @donald123, I am already using PHP with MySQL, Can you maybe give me an example code to perform search and return result. I forgot to mention, I'm new to html, php, MySQL ...  I got it working so far with using a MySQL connector in WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: How do I paste my code if its too long??