# jquery autocomplate source file error

Tags: php, jquery

Whats worng? i make source php file. when i test just open all list open. but not work. example i write

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<script>
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: "text.php"

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this test.php

```
[ "Apple",
"Banana",
"Mango",
"Lemon",
"Öküz helvası"
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery autocomplete with callback ajax json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656523/jquery-autocomplete-with-callback-ajax-json)

Comment: just not work. not selected. just open list