# jQuery autocomplete not filtering and showing all the values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to populate auto suggestions with this javascript code but am unable to get it. I want to load data only if the first characters are matched to the entered data.

```
$(function() {

  $("#city").autocomplete(
  {
      search: function () {},
      source: function (request, response)
      {
          $.ajax(
          {
              url: 'getcities.php',
              dataType: "json",
              data:
              {
                  term: request.term,
              },
              success: function (data)
              {
                  response(data);
              }
          });
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function (event, ui)
      {

      }
  });

});
```

My json format is like this

```
[
    {"id":"1","name":"Mumbai"},
    {"id":"2","name":"Delhi"}
]
```

Comment: `dataType: "json"` requires the returned data to be an `Object`, not an `Array`. Try `{"data": [{"id": ...}, ...]}`

Comment: I want to load `name` in #city and `id` in a field, what should I do?

data:{
    //?????
}

Comment: You can use `jQuery.map()` to provide your data (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35643228/5902913)