# Input Autocomplete fill data from web service

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

How to get data from web service

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
            "DELACOMBE": null,
            "DELAHEY": null,
            "DELAMERE": null,
        }
    });
```

Comment: And what you're showing us from this code? what you've tried so far?

Comment: In autocomplete I want hard coded values from web service.

Comment: Assuming you need to get data from server have you checked out this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656523/jquery-autocomplete-with-callback-ajax-json

Answer (score 0):

On the autocomplete docs. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote there is a remote datasource and remote JSONP datasource example.

The basic of it is to add a source parameter to the endpoint that will return the autocomplete data.

```
$( "input.autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: "api/autocompletedata",
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
  }
});
```