# Set jquery array for CatComplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a working example of JQuery CatComplete, however I am having difficulty getting the example to work with an AJAX variable. Unable to find examples of CatComplete with $ajax request, versus Autocomplete examples which are plentiful.

Below is the data the example uses, which works, but I want to set data to the result of an AJAX request.

```
 var data = [
                { "label": "Test1, "category": "Artist" },
                { "label": "Test2", "category": "Artist" },
                { "label": "Test3", "category": "Musician" }
            ];
```

Desired data set:

```
   var data = $.ajax({
                    url: "/People/AutoComplete",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { Prefix: $("#search").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        data= JSON.stringify(data);
                           alert(data);
                    }
```

When using the second approach, the initial page load has no data -- then the function seems to fire again and has data but the autocomplete does not work. I have checked that the resulting object matches the same structure as the explicit var data =.

Ultimately, the attempt is to use the following example, but with AJAX request for datasource:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery autocomplete with callback ajax json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656523/jquery-autocomplete-with-callback-ajax-json)

Comment: As you've noted, Autocomplete samples are plentiful. However this question pertains to CatComplete, which examples using $ajax are scarce.

Comment: Is the CatComplete not just another usage example of the very same autocomplete functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two problems.

One is an unfortunated clash of variable and parameter names. Both called `data`.

The other is that by the time you initialize your autocomplete widget with `source:data` I assume, your `data` variable has not been initialized yet.

So you need to set the `source` of the autocomplete to the data returned by ajax when the data is returned, not before.

```
$.ajax    ({
  url: "/People/AutoComplete",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    Prefix: $("#search").val()
  },
  success: function (jsondata) {
    $( "#selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "source", JSON.stringify(jsondata));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
<script>
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/People/AutoComplete",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { text: request.term },
            success: function (jsondata) {
                response($.map(data, function (people) {
                    return { lable: people.name, value: people.name } // or the property you want so show at auto complete
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$( "#search" ).catcomplete({
  delay: 500,
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/People/AutoComplete",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: { Prefix: request.term },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        response(data);
      },
      error: function(error){
        console.log(error);
        response([{ "label": "Test0", "category": "BadCoder" }]);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Note that the `source` property can be

- an object (local),
- a string (URL for GET request); Ex: `"/People/AutoComplete?Prefix="+$("#search").val()`
- a `function(request, response);` `request`- search object, `response`- a callback with source data.