# Jquery UI autocomplete plugin not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am a new learner, trying to use JQuery autocomplete plugin. but unable to get the results in autocomplete suggestion, although I am getting the results in `console.log` and as an `alert`. But not in suggestion list.

**Input field**

```
'Name: <input type="text" id="hint" name="hint" />'
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hint").keyup(function () {
            $( "#hint" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            //console.info(request, 'request');
            //console.info(response, 'response');

            $.ajax({
                //q: request.term,
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?Librarian/autocomplete/",
                data: { term: $("#hint").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data)
                    console.log(data);
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
  }); 
});
```

**Controller**

```
function autocomplete($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '') {
    // load model
    $this->load->model("Librarian_model");
    $search_data = $this->input->post('term');


    $result = $this->Librarian_model->get_autocomplete($search_data);

    echo json_encode($result); 
    //returning the result as result_array() also tried implode function but got the error at response

}
```

OUtput at console log : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daI5T.png)

and in alert i got object-object but when I use JSON.stringify output is a array

Comment: Hows the data forming? Please provide the data which you are getting

Comment: 0:
name: "yatish kumar sharma"
__proto__: Object
1:
name: "yatish kumar sharma"
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()

Comment: that's output i am getting in console log

Comment: updated same in question @static startup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery autocomplete with callback ajax json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656523/jquery-autocomplete-with-callback-ajax-json)

Answer (score 0):

Seams that you're ajax response format issue use `map` function to format ajax response -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hint").keyup(function () {
            $( "#hint" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            //console.info(request, 'request');
            //console.info(response, 'response');

            $.ajax({
                //q: request.term,
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?Librarian/autocomplete/",
                data: { term: $("#hint").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data)
                    console.log(data);


                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.name
                        };
                    }));


                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
  }); 
});
```