# How can I get jQuery tagsInput value from text field in Flask

Tags: python, html, jquery, flask

I am working on a search bar field in which the user will enter some keywords with comma-separated and based on the keywords, the corresponding response is shown on the HTML page which works perfectly fine in my case. Now, I have integrated the jQuery tagsInput plugin [Jquery plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Tags-Input-Autocomplete.html) in the search bar in which the user will write a keyword and after pressing comma, the keyword gets converted to tag input. My problem is I am unable to retrieve the value of the entered tag input in the text field which I have to pass to the flask.

**index.html**

```
 <label>
 <input type="text" id="form-tags-4" name="text" placeholder="Enter Tag...">
 </label>
```

Comment: As this plugin support autocomplete so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656523/jquery-autocomplete-with-callback-ajax-json) post should be helpful.